# How to save configuration of jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I want to save the configuration of my jqgrid.

I have seen that this is available through the built in function in jqgrid, but I'm struggeling to get it to work.

I've used the following method to try to export the configuration:

```
$("#mygrid").jqGridExport({exptype:"xmlstring"});
```

Im not quite sure were this code should be executed, but where I tried it, nothing happend.

Comment: Can you post a larger code example?

Comment: I dont have the possibility to provide a lagrer sample right now, but where should I run the code? In loadcomplete, document ready, gridcomplete?

Comment: It depends on when you want to save the configuration of the grid. You could save it in unload event of the page. if you run $("#mygrid").jqGridExport() then you should get the default xmlstring. If you do not then you do not have the correct selector for jquery.

Try running $("#mygrid").jqGridExport() in Chrome's Developer Tools(Inspect Element)